# If view and stored procedure both contain only 1 select statement then what is difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I know performance wise stored procedure is better than view and also there are many benefits with stored procedure. However I am not understanding what is difference in case of both have single select statement as below.

```
Create view viewName
As
    Select * from tableName;
```

and

```
Create procedure spName
As
    Select * from tableName;
```

Hi,  I understand that stored procedure has lot of advantage over view however my question is just based on mentioned query. 
Note - If both looks like above mentioned nothing more then what is difference?

Comment: The stored procedure can be parametrized, e.g. you could retrieve only the rows for a specific search condition, based on a parameter. Views can't do that. On the other hand, views can be made "insertable" so that you can insert values - either by making the view itself insertable, or by providing an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger - stored procedure can't do that

Comment: @marc_s: regarding parameters: a `where` clause on a view can be used to retrieve rows for a specific search condition (but I agree it's not completely the same thing)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: agreed - but the view per se still has all the rows - if you select from it *without* a where clause, you can get all the rows. If the stored procedure *requires* the parameter, you might not be able to do that

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for your input. I understand that stored procedure has lot of advantage over view however my question is just based on mentioned query. If both looks like above mentioned then what is difference?

Comment: See @a_horse_with_no_name's excellent answer - seems up the differences very nicely (e.g. the inability to join a result set from a stored procedure to another set of data)

Comment: OK. But when we just have to use given SP or View for record showing on front end nothing else then is there any difference that makes sense?

Comment: You have a complete answer from a a_horse_with_no_name.  If you aren't going to do any of the things you can't do with one or the other then they are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several differences:

What the procedure can't do:

- You can't join the result of the procedure to another table.
- You can't use a WHERE clause to reduce the number of rows returned by the procedure
- You can't use the result of the stored procedure in a sub-select
- You can't insert data "into" the procedure (as you can do with a view)

What the view can't do

- You can't apply (complex) transformations to the data while being retrieved (apart from simple function to change single values)
- You can't pass a parameter to a view (although a WHERE clause appended to a view could be used for a similar purpose)

Answer (score 0):

None in a trivial example like that.  A **View** is just a select statement into the table.  It's done for clarity or ease of use.

Wheres a stored procedure can do just the select.  But it does a lot more.  You can process each row and manipulate the columns, you can query other tables and return the row optionally or combined with other rows or other table's rows.  You can write a "program" inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure:

- accepts parameters
- can NOT be used as building block in a larger query
- can contain several statements, loops, `IF ELSE`, etc.
- can perform modifications to one or several tables
- can NOT be used as the target of an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

View:

- does NOT accept parameters
- can be used as building block in a larger query
- can contain only one single `SELECT` query
- can NOT perform modifications to any table
- but can (sometimes) be used as the target of an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.